# ORA-00920: invalid relational operator, on application level

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager

I have an application running on Wildfly 10.1.0 and I'm having this weird issue where I create a TypedQuery using EntityManager, set all the parameters and when I use query.getResultList(), it gives this exception, but when I get the query created by hibernate, paste on sqldeveloper and change the ? for the parameter values, it executes without any problem. Please help me, I'm already clueless.
This is the query converted by hibernate:

```
select rbpenginer0_.RBP_ENG_RISK_ID as RBP_ENG_RISK_ID1_190_, rbpenginer0_.ACTIVE as ACTIVE2_190_, rbpenginer0_.DT_INSERT as DT_INSERT3_190_, rbpenginer0_.INSERT_USER_ID as INSERT_USER_ID18_190_, rbpenginer0_.STATUS as STATUS4_190_, rbpenginer0_.DT_UPDATE as DT_UPDATE5_190_, rbpenginer0_.UPDATE_USER_ID as UPDATE_USER_ID19_190_, rbpenginer0_.LINE as LINE6_190_, rbpenginer0_.MAX_AGE_VEHICLE as MAX_AGE_VEHICLE7_190_, rbpenginer0_.MAX_DEPOSIT_PERCENT as MAX_DEPOSIT_PERCEN8_190_, rbpenginer0_.MAX_DURATION as MAX_DURATION9_190_, rbpenginer0_.MAX_MODEL_RATE as MAX_MODEL_RATE10_190_, rbpenginer0_.MIN_AGE_VEHICLE as MIN_AGE_VEHICLE11_190_, rbpenginer0_.MIN_DEPOSIT_PERCENT as MIN_DEPOSIT_PERCE12_190_, rbpenginer0_.MIN_DURATION as MIN_DURATION13_190_, rbpenginer0_.MIN_MODEL_RATE as MIN_MODEL_RATE14_190_, rbpenginer0_.PERSON_TYPE as PERSON_TYPE15_190_, rbpenginer0_.RATE_COR as RATE_COR16_190_, rbpenginer0_.RATING_ABC as RATING_ABC17_190_, rbpenginer0_.SALE_TYPE_ID as SALE_TYPE_ID20_190_ from TB_RBP_ENG_RISK rbpenginer0_ where rbpenginer0_.ACTIVE=? and rbpenginer0_.STATUS=? and ((1 , rbpenginer0_.RBP_ENG_RISK_ID) in (?))
```

And this is the query after replacing the parameters:

```
select rbpenginer0_.RBP_ENG_RISK_ID as RBP_ENG_RISK_ID1_190_, rbpenginer0_.ACTIVE as ACTIVE2_190_, rbpenginer0_.DT_INSERT as DT_INSERT3_190_, rbpenginer0_.INSERT_USER_ID as INSERT_USER_ID18_190_, rbpenginer0_.STATUS as STATUS4_190_, rbpenginer0_.DT_UPDATE as DT_UPDATE5_190_, rbpenginer0_.UPDATE_USER_ID as UPDATE_USER_ID19_190_, rbpenginer0_.LINE as LINE6_190_, rbpenginer0_.MAX_AGE_VEHICLE as MAX_AGE_VEHICLE7_190_, rbpenginer0_.MAX_DEPOSIT_PERCENT as MAX_DEPOSIT_PERCEN8_190_, rbpenginer0_.MAX_DURATION as MAX_DURATION9_190_, rbpenginer0_.MAX_MODEL_RATE as MAX_MODEL_RATE10_190_, rbpenginer0_.MIN_AGE_VEHICLE as MIN_AGE_VEHICLE11_190_, rbpenginer0_.MIN_DEPOSIT_PERCENT as MIN_DEPOSIT_PERCE12_190_, rbpenginer0_.MIN_DURATION as MIN_DURATION13_190_, rbpenginer0_.MIN_MODEL_RATE as MIN_MODEL_RATE14_190_, rbpenginer0_.PERSON_TYPE as PERSON_TYPE15_190_, rbpenginer0_.RATE_COR as RATE_COR16_190_, rbpenginer0_.RATING_ABC as RATING_ABC17_190_, rbpenginer0_.SALE_TYPE_ID as SALE_TYPE_ID20_190_ from TB_RBP_ENG_RISK rbpenginer0_ where rbpenginer0_.ACTIVE=1 and rbpenginer0_.STATUS='PENDING_REMOVAL' and ((1 , rbpenginer0_.RBP_ENG_RISK_ID) in ((1, 23800), (1, 23801), (1, 23802), (1, 23803), (1, 23804), (1, 23805), (1, 23806), (1, 23807), (1, 23808), (1, 23809), (1, 23810), (1, 23811), (1, 23812), (1, 23813), (1, 23814), (1, 23815), (1, 23816), (1, 23817), (1, 23818), (1, 23819), (1, 23820), (1, 23821), (1, 23822), (1, 23823), (1, 23824), (1, 23825), (1, 23826), (1, 23827), (1, 23828), (1, 23829), (1, 23830), (1, 23831), (1, 23832), (1, 23833), (1, 23834), (1, 23835), (1, 23836), (1, 23837), (1, 23838), (1, 23839), (1, 23840), (1, 23841), (1, 23842), (1, 23843), (1, 23844), (1, 23845), (1, 23846), (1, 23847), (1, 23848), (1, 23849), (1, 23850), (1, 23851), (1, 23852), (1, 23853), (1, 23854), (1, 23855), (1, 23856), (1, 23857), (1, 23858), (1, 23859), (1, 23860), (1, 23861), (1, 23862), (1, 23863), (1, 23864), (1, 23865), (1, 23866), (1, 23867), (1, 23868), (1, 23869), (1, 23870), (1, 23871), (1, 23872), (1, 23873), (1, 23874), (1, 23875), (1, 23876), (1, 23877), (1, 23878), (1, 23879), (1, 23880), (1, 23881), (1, 23882), (1, 23883), (1, 23884), (1, 23885), (1, 23886), (1, 23887), (1, 23888), (1, 23889), (1, 23890), (1, 23891), (1, 23892), (1, 23893), (1, 23894), (1, 23895), (1, 23896), (1, 23897), (1, 23898), (1, 23899), (1, 23900), (1, 21852), (1, 23901), (1, 21853), (1, 23902), (1, 21854), (1, 23903), (1, 21855), (1, 23904), (1, 21856), (1, 23905), (1, 21857), (1, 23906), (1, 21858), (1, 23907), (1, 21859), (1, 23908), (1, 21860), (1, 23909), (1, 21861), (1, 23910), (1, 21862), (1, 23911), (1, 21863), (1, 23912), (1, 21864), (1, 23913), (1, 21865), (1, 23914), (1, 21866), (1, 23915), (1, 21867), (1, 23916), (1, 21868), (1, 23917), (1, 21869), (1, 23918), (1, 21870), (1, 23919), (1, 21871), (1, 23920), (1, 21872), (1, 23921), (1, 21873), (1, 23922), (1, 21874), (1, 23923), (1, 21875), (1, 23924), (1, 21876), (1, 23925), (1, 21877), (1, 23926), (1, 21878), (1, 23927), (1, 21879), (1, 23928), (1, 21880), (1, 23929), (1, 21881), (1, 23930), (1, 21882), (1, 23931), (1, 21883), (1, 23932), (1, 21884), (1, 23933), (1, 21885), (1, 23934), (1, 21886), (1, 23935), (1, 21887), (1, 23936), (1, 21888), (1, 23937), (1, 21889), (1, 23938), (1, 21890), (1, 23939), (1, 21891), (1, 23940), (1, 21892), (1, 23941), (1, 21893), (1, 23942), (1, 21894), (1, 23943), (1, 21895), (1, 23944), (1, 21896), (1, 23945), (1, 21897), (1, 23946), (1, 21898), (1, 23947), (1, 21899), (1, 23948), (1, 21900), (1, 23949), (1, 21901), (1, 23950), (1, 21902), (1, 23951), (1, 21903), (1, 23952), (1, 21904), (1, 23953), (1, 21905), (1, 23954), (1, 21906), (1, 23955), (1, 21907), (1, 23956), (1, 21908), (1, 23957), (1, 21909), (1, 23958), (1, 21910), (1, 23959), (1, 21911), (1, 23960), (1, 21912), (1, 23961), (1, 21913), (1, 23962), (1, 21914), (1, 23963), (1, 21915), (1, 23964), (1, 21916), (1, 23965), (1, 21917), (1, 23966), (1, 21918), (1, 23967), (1, 21919), (1, 23968), (1, 21920), (1, 23969), (1, 21921), (1, 23970), (1, 21922), (1, 23971), (1, 21923), (1, 23972), (1, 21924), (1, 23973), (1, 21925), (1, 23974), (1, 21926), (1, 23975), (1, 21927), (1, 23976), (1, 21928), (1, 23977), (1, 21929), (1, 23978), (1, 21930), (1, 23979), (1, 21931), (1, 23980), (1, 21932), (1, 23981), (1, 21933), (1, 23982), (1, 21934), (1, 23983), (1, 21935), (1, 23984), (1, 21936), (1, 23985), (1, 21937), (1, 23986), (1, 21938), (1, 23987), (1, 21939), (1, 23988), (1, 21940), (1, 23989), (1, 21941), (1, 23990), (1, 21942), (1, 23991), (1, 21943), (1, 23992), (1, 21944), (1, 23993), (1, 21945), (1, 23994), (1, 21946), (1, 23995), (1, 21947), (1, 23996), (1, 21948), (1, 23997), (1, 21949), (1, 23998), (1, 21950), (1, 23999), (1, 21951), (1, 24000), (1, 21952), (1, 24001), (1, 21953), (1, 24002), (1, 21954), (1, 24003), (1, 21955), (1, 24004), (1, 21956), (1, 24005), (1, 21957), (1, 24006), (1, 21958), (1, 24007), (1, 21959), (1, 24008), (1, 21960), (1, 24009), (1, 21961), (1, 24010), (1, 21962), (1, 24011), (1, 21963), (1, 24012), (1, 21964), (1, 24013), (1, 21965), (1, 24014), (1, 21966), (1, 24015), (1, 21967), (1, 24016), (1, 21968), (1, 24017), (1, 21969), (1, 24018), (1, 21970), (1, 24019), (1, 21971), (1, 24020), (1, 21972), (1, 24021), (1, 21973), (1, 24022), (1, 21974), (1, 24023), (1, 21975), (1, 24024), (1, 21976), (1, 24025), (1, 21977), (1, 24026), (1, 21978), (1, 24027), (1, 21979), (1, 24028), (1, 21980), (1, 24029), (1, 21981), (1, 24030), (1, 21982), (1, 24031), (1, 21983), (1, 24032), (1, 21984), (1, 24033), (1, 21985), (1, 24034), (1, 21986), (1, 24035), (1, 21987), (1, 24036), (1, 21988), (1, 24037), (1, 21989), (1, 24038), (1, 21990), (1, 24039), (1, 21991), (1, 24040), (1, 21992), (1, 24041), (1, 21993), (1, 24042), (1, 21994), (1, 24043), (1, 21995), (1, 24044), (1, 21996), (1, 21997), (1, 24045), (1, 21998), (1, 24046), (1, 21999), (1, 24047), (1, 24048), (1, 22000), (1, 22001), (1, 24049), (1, 22002), (1, 24050), (1, 22003), (1, 24051), (1, 22004), (1, 24052), (1, 22005), (1, 24053), (1, 22006), (1, 24054), (1, 22007), (1, 24055), (1, 22008), (1, 24056), (1, 22009), (1, 24057), (1, 24058), (1, 22010), (1, 22011), (1, 24059), (1, 22012), (1, 24060), (1, 22013), (1, 24061), (1, 22014), (1, 24062), (1, 22015), (1, 24063), (1, 22016), (1, 24064), (1, 22017), (1, 24065), (1, 22018), (1, 24066), (1, 22019), (1, 24067), (1, 22020), (1, 24068), (1, 22021), (1, 24069), (1, 22022), (1, 24070), (1, 22023), (1, 24071), (1, 22024), (1, 24072), (1, 22025), (1, 24073), (1, 22026), (1, 24074), (1, 22027), (1, 24075), (1, 22028), (1, 24076), (1, 22029), (1, 24077), (1, 22030), (1, 24078), (1, 22031), (1, 24079), (1, 22032), (1, 24080), (1, 22033), (1, 24081), (1, 22034), (1, 24082), (1, 22035), (1, 24083), (1, 22036), (1, 24084), (1, 22037), (1, 24085), (1, 22038), (1, 24086), (1, 22039), (1, 24087), (1, 22040), (1, 24088), (1, 22041), (1, 24089), (1, 22042), (1, 24090), (1, 22043), (1, 24091), (1, 22044), (1, 24092), (1, 22045), (1, 24093), (1, 22046), (1, 24094), (1, 22047), (1, 24095), (1, 22048), (1, 24096), (1, 22049), (1, 24097), (1, 22050), (1, 24098), (1, 22051), (1, 24099), (1, 22052), (1, 24100), (1, 22053), (1, 24101), (1, 22054), (1, 24102), (1, 22055), (1, 24103), (1, 22056), (1, 24104), (1, 22057), (1, 24105), (1, 22058), (1, 24106), (1, 22059), (1, 24107), (1, 22060), (1, 24108), (1, 22061), (1, 24109), (1, 22062), (1, 24110), (1, 22063), (1, 24111), (1, 22064), (1, 24112), (1, 22065), (1, 24113), (1, 22066), (1, 24114), (1, 22067), (1, 24115), (1, 22068), (1, 24116), (1, 22069), (1, 24117), (1, 24118), (1, 22070), (1, 24119), (1, 22071), (1, 24120), (1, 22072), (1, 24121), (1, 22073), (1, 24122), (1, 22074), (1, 24123), (1, 22075), (1, 24124), (1, 22076), (1, 24125), (1, 22077), (1, 24126), (1, 22078), (1, 24127), (1, 22079), (1, 24128), (1, 22080), (1, 24129), (1, 22081), (1, 24130), (1, 22082), (1, 24131), (1, 22083), (1, 24132), (1, 22084), (1, 24133), (1, 22085), (1, 24134), (1, 22086), (1, 24135), (1, 22087), (1, 24136), (1, 22088), (1, 24137), (1, 22089), (1, 24138), (1, 22090), (1, 24139), (1, 22091), (1, 24140), (1, 22092), (1, 24141), (1, 22093), (1, 24142), (1, 22094), (1, 24143), (1, 22095), (1, 24144), (1, 22096), (1, 24145), (1, 22097), (1, 24146), (1, 22098), (1, 24147), (1, 22099), (1, 24148), (1, 22100), (1, 24149), (1, 22101), (1, 24150), (1, 22102), (1, 24151), (1, 22103), (1, 24152), (1, 22104), (1, 24153), (1, 22105), (1, 24154), (1, 22106), (1, 24155), (1, 22107), (1, 24156), (1, 22108), (1, 24157), (1, 22109), (1, 24158), (1, 22110), (1, 24159), (1, 22111), (1, 24160), (1, 22112), (1, 24161), (1, 22113), (1, 24162), (1, 22114), (1, 24163), (1, 22115), (1, 24164), (1, 22116), (1, 24165), (1, 22117), (1, 24166), (1, 22118), (1, 24167), (1, 22119), (1, 24168), (1, 22120), (1, 24169), (1, 22121), (1, 24170), (1, 22122), (1, 24171), (1, 22123), (1, 24172), (1, 22124), (1, 24173), (1, 22125), (1, 24174), (1, 22126), (1, 24175), (1, 22127), (1, 24176), (1, 22128), (1, 24177), (1, 22129), (1, 24178), (1, 22130), (1, 24179), (1, 22131), (1, 24180), (1, 22132), (1, 24181), (1, 22133), (1, 24182), (1, 22134), (1, 24183), (1, 22135), (1, 24184), (1, 22136), (1, 24185), (1, 22137), (1, 24186), (1, 22138), (1, 24187), (1, 22139), (1, 24188), (1, 22140), (1, 24189), (1, 22141), (1, 22142), (1, 24190), (1, 22143), (1, 24191), (1, 22144), (1, 24192), (1, 22145), (1, 24193), (1, 22146), (1, 24194), (1, 24195), (1, 22147), (1, 22148), (1, 24196), (1, 22149), (1, 24197), (1, 22150), (1, 24198), (1, 22151), (1, 24199), (1, 22152), (1, 24200), (1, 22153), (1, 24201), (1, 22154), (1, 24202), (1, 22155), (1, 24203), (1, 22156), (1, 24204), (1, 22157), (1, 24205), (1, 22158), (1, 24206), (1, 22159), (1, 24207), (1, 22160), (1, 24208), (1, 22161), (1, 24209), (1, 22162), (1, 24210), (1, 22163), (1, 24211), (1, 22164), (1, 24212), (1, 22165), (1, 24213), (1, 22166), (1, 24214), (1, 22167), (1, 24215), (1, 22168), (1, 24216), (1, 22169), (1, 24217), (1, 22170), (1, 24218), (1, 22171), (1, 24219), (1, 22172), (1, 24220), (1, 22173), (1, 24221), (1, 22174), (1, 24222), (1, 22175), (1, 24223), (1, 22176), (1, 24224), (1, 22177), (1, 24225), (1, 22178), (1, 24226), (1, 22179), (1, 24227), (1, 22180), (1, 24228), (1, 22181), (1, 24229), (1, 22182), (1, 24230), (1, 22183), (1, 24231), (1, 22184), (1, 24232), (1, 22185), (1, 24233), (1, 22186), (1, 24234), (1, 22187), (1, 24235), (1, 22188), (1, 24236), (1, 22189), (1, 24237), (1, 22190), (1, 24238), (1, 22191), (1, 24239), (1, 22192), (1, 24240), (1, 22193), (1, 24241), (1, 22194), (1, 24242), (1, 22195), (1, 24243), (1, 22196), (1, 24244), (1, 22197), (1, 24245), (1, 22198), (1, 24246), (1, 22199), (1, 24247), (1, 22200), (1, 24248), (1, 22201), (1, 24249), (1, 22202), (1, 24250), (1, 22203), (1, 24251), (1, 22204), (1, 24252), (1, 22205), (1, 24253), (1, 22206), (1, 24254), (1, 22207), (1, 24255), (1, 22208), (1, 24256), (1, 22209), (1, 24257), (1, 22210), (1, 24258), (1, 22211), (1, 24259), (1, 22212), (1, 24260), (1, 22213), (1, 24261), (1, 22214), (1, 24262), (1, 22215), (1, 24263), (1, 22216), (1, 24264), (1, 22217), (1, 24265), (1, 22218), (1, 24266), (1, 22219), (1, 24267), (1, 22220), (1, 24268), (1, 22221), (1, 24269), (1, 22222), (1, 24270), (1, 22223), (1, 24271), (1, 22224), (1, 24272), (1, 22225), (1, 24273), (1, 22226), (1, 24274), (1, 22227), (1, 24275), (1, 22228), (1, 24276), (1, 22229), (1, 24277), (1, 22230), (1, 24278), (1, 22231), (1, 24279), (1, 22232), (1, 24280), (1, 22233), (1, 24281), (1, 22234), (1, 24282), (1, 22235), (1, 24283), (1, 22236), (1, 24284), (1, 22237), (1, 24285), (1, 22238), (1, 24286), (1, 22239), (1, 24287), (1, 22240), (1, 24288), (1, 22241), (1, 24289), (1, 22242), (1, 24290), (1, 22243), (1, 24291), (1, 22244), (1, 24292), (1, 22245), (1, 24293), (1, 22246), (1, 24294), (1, 22247), (1, 24295), (1, 22248), (1, 24296), (1, 22249), (1, 24297), (1, 22250), (1, 24298), (1, 22251), (1, 24299), (1, 22252), (1, 24300), (1, 22253), (1, 24301), (1, 22254), (1, 24302), (1, 22255), (1, 24303), (1, 22256), (1, 24304), (1, 22257), (1, 24305), (1, 22258), (1, 24306), (1, 22259), (1, 24307), (1, 22260), (1, 24308), (1, 22261), (1, 24309), (1, 22262), (1, 24310), (1, 22263), (1, 24311), (1, 22264), (1, 24312), (1, 22265), (1, 24313), (1, 22266), (1, 24314), (1, 22267), (1, 24315), (1, 22268), (1, 24316), (1, 22269), (1, 24317), (1, 22270), (1, 24318), (1, 22271), (1, 24319), (1, 22272), (1, 24320), (1, 22273), (1, 24321), (1, 22274), (1, 24322), (1, 22275), (1, 24323), (1, 22276), (1, 24324), (1, 22277), (1, 24325), (1, 22278), (1, 24326), (1, 22279), (1, 24327), (1, 22280), (1, 24328), (1, 22281), (1, 24329), (1, 22282), (1, 24330), (1, 22283), (1, 24331), (1, 22284), (1, 24332), (1, 22285), (1, 24333), (1, 22286), (1, 24334), (1, 22287), (1, 24335), (1, 22288), (1, 24336), (1, 22289), (1, 24337), (1, 22290), (1, 24338), (1, 22291), (1, 24339), (1, 22292), (1, 24340), (1, 22293), (1, 24341), (1, 22294), (1, 24342), (1, 22295), (1, 24343), (1, 22296), (1, 24344), (1, 22297), (1, 24345), (1, 22298), (1, 24346), (1, 22299), (1, 24347), (1, 22300), (1, 24348), (1, 22301), (1, 24349), (1, 22302), (1, 24350), (1, 22303), (1, 24351), (1, 22304), (1, 24352), (1, 22305), (1, 24353), (1, 22306), (1, 24354), (1, 22307), (1, 24355), (1, 22308), (1, 24356), (1, 22309), (1, 24357), (1, 22310), (1, 24358), (1, 22311), (1, 24359), (1, 22312), (1, 24360), (1, 22313), (1, 24361), (1, 22314), (1, 24362), (1, 22315), (1, 24363), (1, 22316), (1, 24364), (1, 22317), (1, 24365), (1, 22318), (1, 24366), (1, 22319), (1, 24367), (1, 22320), (1, 24368), (1, 22321), (1, 24369), (1, 22322), (1, 24370), (1, 22323), (1, 24371), (1, 22324), (1, 24372), (1, 22325), (1, 24373), (1, 22326), (1, 24374), (1, 22327), (1, 24375), (1, 22328), (1, 24376), (1, 22329), (1, 24377), (1, 22330), (1, 24378), (1, 22331), (1, 24379), (1, 22332), (1, 24380), (1, 22333), (1, 24381), (1, 22334), (1, 24382), (1, 22335), (1, 24383), (1, 22336), (1, 24384), (1, 22337), (1, 24385), (1, 22338), (1, 24386), (1, 22339), (1, 24387), (1, 22340), (1, 24388), (1, 22341), (1, 24389), (1, 22342), (1, 24390), (1, 22343), (1, 24391), (1, 22344), (1, 24392), (1, 22345), (1, 24393), (1, 22346), (1, 24394), (1, 22347), (1, 24395), (1, 22348), (1, 24396), (1, 22349), (1, 24397), (1, 22350), (1, 24398), (1, 22351), (1, 24399), (1, 22352), (1, 24400), (1, 22353), (1, 24401), (1, 22354), (1, 24402), (1, 22355), (1, 24403), (1, 22356), (1, 24404), (1, 22357), (1, 24405), (1, 22358), (1, 24406), (1, 22359), (1, 24407), (1, 22360), (1, 24408), (1, 22361), (1, 24409), (1, 22362), (1, 24410), (1, 22363), (1, 24411), (1, 22364), (1, 24412), (1, 22365), (1, 24413), (1, 22366), (1, 24414), (1, 22367), (1, 24415), (1, 22368), (1, 24416), (1, 22369), (1, 24417), (1, 22370), (1, 24418), (1, 22371), (1, 24419), (1, 22372), (1, 24420), (1, 22373), (1, 24421), (1, 22374), (1, 24422), (1, 22375), (1, 24423), (1, 22376), (1, 24424), (1, 22377), (1, 24425), (1, 24426), (1, 24427), (1, 24428), (1, 24429), (1, 24430), (1, 24431), (1, 24432), (1, 24433), (1, 24434), (1, 24435), (1, 24436), (1, 24437), (1, 24438), (1, 24439), (1, 24440), (1, 24441), (1, 24442), (1, 24443), (1, 24444), (1, 24445), (1, 24446), (1, 24447), (1, 24448), (1, 24449), (1, 24450), (1, 24451), (1, 24452), (1, 24453), (1, 24454), (1, 24455), (1, 24456), (1, 24457), (1, 24458), (1, 24459), (1, 24460), (1, 24461), (1, 24462), (1, 24463), (1, 24464), (1, 24465), (1, 24466), (1, 24467), (1, 24468), (1, 24469), (1, 24470), (1, 24471), (1, 24472), (1, 24473), (1, 24474), (1, 24475), (1, 24476), (1, 24477), (1, 24478), (1, 24479), (1, 24480), (1, 24481), (1, 24482), (1, 24483), (1, 24484), (1, 24485)));
```

First 30 lines of the stack trace:
0 = {StackTraceElement@30337} "org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)"
1 = {StackTraceElement@30338} "org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)"
2 = {StackTraceElement@30339} "org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:492)"
3 = {StackTraceElement@30340} "com.rci.omega2.ejb.dao.RbpGenericDAO.findAll(RbpGenericDAO.java:25)"
4 = {StackTraceElement@30341} "com.rci.omega2.ejb.bo.EngineBO.approveDeactivation(EngineBO.java:881)"
5 = {StackTraceElement@30342} "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"
6 = {StackTraceElement@30343} "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)"
7 = {StackTraceElement@30344} "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"
8 = {StackTraceElement@30345} "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"
9 = {StackTraceElement@30346} "org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)"
10 = {StackTraceElement@30347} "org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)"
11 = {StackTraceElement@30348} "org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)"
12 = {StackTraceElement@30349} "org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)"
13 = {StackTraceElement@30350} "org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)"
14 = {StackTraceElement@30351} "org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)"
15 = {StackTraceElement@30352} "org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)"
16 = {StackTraceElement@30353} "org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)"
17 = {StackTraceElement@30354} "org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)"
18 = {StackTraceElement@30355} "org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)"
19 = {StackTraceElement@30356} "org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)"
20 = {StackTraceElement@30357} "org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)"
21 = {StackTraceElement@30358} "org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)"
22 = {StackTraceElement@30359} "org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)"
23 = {StackTraceElement@30360} "org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)"
24 = {StackTraceElement@30361} "org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)"
25 = {StackTraceElement@30362} "org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)"
26 = {StackTraceElement@30363} "org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)"
27 = {StackTraceElement@30364} "org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)"
28 = {StackTraceElement@30365} "org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)"
29 = {StackTraceElement@30366} "org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)"
30 = {StackTraceElement@30367} "org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)"

Least 30 lines of the stack trace:
130 = {StackTraceElement@30568} "io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)"
131 = {StackTraceElement@30569} "io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)"
132 = {StackTraceElement@30570} "io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)"
133 = {StackTraceElement@30571} "io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)"
134 = {StackTraceElement@30572} "io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)"
135 = {StackTraceElement@30573} "io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)"
136 = {StackTraceElement@30574} "io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)"
137 = {StackTraceElement@30575} "io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)"
138 = {StackTraceElement@30576} "io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)"
139 = {StackTraceElement@30577} "org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)"
140 = {StackTraceElement@30578} "io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)"
141 = {StackTraceElement@30579} "io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)"
142 = {StackTraceElement@30580} "io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)"
143 = {StackTraceElement@30581} "io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)"
144 = {StackTraceElement@30582} "io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)"
145 = {StackTraceElement@30583} "io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)"
146 = {StackTraceElement@30584} "io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)"
147 = {StackTraceElement@30585} "io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)"
148 = {StackTraceElement@30586} "io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)"
149 = {StackTraceElement@30587} "io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)"
150 = {StackTraceElement@30588} "io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)"
151 = {StackTraceElement@30589} "io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)"
152 = {StackTraceElement@30590} "io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)"
153 = {StackTraceElement@30591} "io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)"
154 = {StackTraceElement@30592} "io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)"
155 = {StackTraceElement@30593} "io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)"
156 = {StackTraceElement@30594} "io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)"
157 = {StackTraceElement@30595} "io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)"
158 = {StackTraceElement@30596} "io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)"
159 = {StackTraceElement@30597} "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)"
160 = {StackTraceElement@30598} "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)"
161 = {StackTraceElement@30599} "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"

Comment: show th last 30 lines of trace back and the first 30, because the query has no errors

Comment: my guess is your generated sql has just too many literals in the *in(...)* field

Comment: I read this question from the phone, and it is not so simple to even see the code... Did you try to execute generated query by yourself from SQL Developer? Does it run ok? Did you try to split this long list into parts or at least try to execute it with few items in the list to find, if it is problematic at all or due to some values in the list?

Comment: Yes. I run it without any problems on SQL Developer, the (1, id) was to make sure I could add more than 999 items into the in.

Comment: I don't know much Hibernate, but if the "?" stands for a standard bind variable, then you can't bind in this way.  If you want COL in (  <5 values> ), you need to code COL in ( ?, ?,?, ?,?,) not just COL in (?)

Comment: You surely don't. When I do something like "WHERE (1, ID) IN (?)", I pass a String like 
"(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)", that will become "WHERE (1, ID) IN ((1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3))", but if I passed just an array of ids, the result would be indeed wrong.

Comment: @nbk is there anything else you need?

Comment: @astentx is there anything else you need?

Comment: *When I do something like "WHERE (1, ID) IN (?)", I pass a String like "(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)"* Bind variable replaces **the data**, not the text. It is not just a replacement of some part of SQL statement, and its content is processed at the execution time. So what your statement is essentially doing is a comparison of tuple with a (single-item) list of strings, which of course is invalid SQL statement. Try to prepare your original statement in SQL Developer and you'll see it is not working

Comment: And what I was talking about in my previous message: you need to provide **minimal** reproducible example: reading that list with hundreds of fields in the `select` is a waste of the time. The same is applicable to the list of a thousand of tuples after `in`. Does it matter to have all this in the question? Do you really think someone can extract a single field from the list or a single value from filter and say: "Hey, the error is here!"? I think the error appears regardless of the number of passed values or projected fields, so please, do not include exccessive code